# Startup Services AddAuthorization AddPolicy: EmptyRequirement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, policy, requirements, authorize-attribute

I'm little bit new in web development. I have an RestController which has many method e.g. (Get, GetById, Create, Update). I use Authorize Attribute, which used with Policy. This policy depend on a bool variable. You can see at below.

Now I use this workaround but I search more nice solution.

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
    {
        o.AddPolicy("UserRoleCheck", p =>
        {
            if (C.RequiredAuth)
            {
                p.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                p.AssertRole(Roles.User);
            }
            else
            {
                p.AddRequirements(new EmptyRequirement()); // Here I don't want to else branch
            }

        });
    });  

public class EmptyRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<EmptyRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, EmptyRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

It's work, but can You offer me more beautiful solution?

Answer (score 0):

For your current design, it is caused by that `Policy` must contains at least one requirement.

Not sure what is the defination for `C`, I suggest you implement `UserRoleCheckRequirement` and move the `C` to `UserRoleCheckRequirement` to return `context.Succeed(requirement);`. And then check `AuthenticatedUser` and other authorization logic in `HandleRequirementAsync`.